# Relative layout in android

Tags: java, android, layout, resolution, android-relativelayout

How i can put views in screen relative to other views? For example i have a button named btn1 and another named btn2. I want to set btn2 margin top from btn1 not entire screen!!

```
//define btn1 here
.
.
.
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"     //5dp from btn1
```

How i can do this? My main problem is layouts and positioning on screen for different screen sizes.

Comment: past entire xml here and be specific

Comment: @Dr.nik: my question is: how i can position a view relative to other views? i don't have any specific XML file

Answer (score 0):

set `android:layout_below="@+id/btn1"` and `android:layout_marginTop="5dp"`  in propery of btn2.

Comment: i do this but still my widgets related with main layout.there is no any connection with widgets